# Microsoft graph - listing emails - Access to OData is disabled

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I would like to use the Microsoft Graph API to programmatically check an Office365 Mailbox.

I followed all documentation, i.e.

- Created a app on Microsoft Identity Platform, with permissions `Mail.Read`, `MailboxSettings.Read`, `User.Read.All` - all with Admin Consent
- Created a secret code
- Created a `mail-enabled security group` including the email addresses that should be accessed by the script
- Created a `ApplicationAccessPolicy` to link those two items

Now,

- I can request an access token
- I can use this access token to get the
  list of users ( `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/` )
- But when I try to get the list of messages of a specific user ( `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/USERIDHERE/messages` ) I get the following 403 error:

```
    {
      "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access to OData is disabled.",
        "innerError": {
          "request-id": "73db8b50-1f16-4301-abbd-d3fbbc78ca9b",
          "date": "2019-12-20T16:08:34"
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that user has an Exchange Online mailbox licensed and provisioned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually solved itself, after waiting about 1 hour.

I guess the culprit was the Exchange cache.